# Job for mariadb.service failed

Tags: linux, mariadb, opensuse

Iam using Opensuse leap 15.2 and when I start the mariadb from terminal:

```
systemctl start mariadb
```

i have this error:

```
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl  status mariadb.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.
```

and The resulte :

```
journalctl  -xe
```

Is:

```
Sep 28 17:36:05 localhost.localdomain mysql-systemd-helper[6865]: mysql.time_zone_leap_second                        OK
Sep 28 17:36:05 localhost.localdomain mysql-systemd-helper[6865]: mysql.time_zone_name                               OK
Sep 28 17:36:05 localhost.localdomain mysql-systemd-helper[6865]: mysql.time_zone_transition                         OK
Sep 28 17:36:05 localhost.localdomain mysql-systemd-helper[6865]: mysql.time_zone_transition_type                    OK
Sep 28 17:36:05 localhost.localdomain mysql-systemd-helper[6865]: mysql.transaction_registry                         OK
Sep 28 17:36:05 localhost.localdomain mysql-systemd-helper[6865]: Phase 2/7: Installing used storage engines... Skipped
Sep 28 17:36:05 localhost.localdomain mysql-systemd-helper[6865]: Phase 3/7: Fixing views
Sep 28 17:36:05 localhost.localdomain mysql-systemd-helper[6865]: /usr/bin/mysqlcheck: Got error: 1102: Incorrect database name '#mysql50#.cache>
Sep 28 17:36:05 localhost.localdomain mysql-systemd-helper[6865]: FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
Sep 28 17:36:05 localhost.localdomain mysql-systemd-helper[6865]: Upgrade failed
Sep 28 17:36:05 localhost.localdomain mysql-systemd-helper[6865]: Shutting down protected MySQL
Sep 28 17:36:07 localhost.localdomain mysql-systemd-helper[6865]: Final cleanup
Sep 28 17:36:07 localhost.localdomain mysql-systemd-helper[6865]: Something failed during upgrade, please check logs
Sep 28 17:36:07 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 28 17:36:07 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
-- Subject: Unit mariadb.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mariadb.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Sep 28 17:36:07 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 28 17:36:07 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

can any one help me please?!

Comment: Unfortunately "systemctl status" only shows the last few log lines, output of e.g.  "journalctl -u mariadb | tail 100" would be more useful here to get a more complete picture of the situation ...

Answer (score 0):

I Reinstalled Opensuse And The Problem Is Solved.
Thanks.